# Where in the Quran is Jesus' appearance described?

Tags: prophet-isa

I'm a Jewish follower of Jesus, and was recently surprised to see Linda Sarsour, the Muslim women's leader in the US, tweeting about Jesus' appearance in the Quran:

[image]

Ignoring for a moment the ahistoricity of Jesus being Palestinian, **are there passages in the Quran about Jesus' appearance**? Some quick searching around the web shows some possible references in hadith traditions, but I haven't found anything in the Quran itself.

Comment: This description doesn't exist in the qur'an, but it was mentioned in the sunnah or ahadith. I'd wonder if there's a description of any human in the qur'an at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no description of the appearance of Jesus عليه السلام in the Quran. She is likely referring to the ahadith.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found an online reference for this: Hadith Volume 4 Book 55 Number 648: "The prophet said, "I saw Moses, Jesus and Abraham (on the night of my Ascension to the heavens). Jesus was of red complexion, curly hair and a broad chest. Moses was of brown complexion, straight hair and tall stature as if he was from the people of Az-Zutt." https://quranx.com/hadith/bukhari/USC-MSA/Volume-4/Book-55/Hadith-648/

Answer (score 1):

Traits taken from ahadith:

•Moderate height, he's not tall nor short (sahih, Al-albani 4324 and sahih Bukhari 3394)

•Brown skinned with a white/red hue (especially his cheeks) (sahih Bukhari 3394 and 3441 and 3440 and Al-Albani 4324)

•Straight hair that reaches the shoulders (sahih bukhari 3441 and 3440)

•Broad chest, thick muscled (I didn't rly know how to translate this one) (Sahih Bukhari 3438) (*the word جعد is mostly used for hair but in this context it's referring to his body)

•his head is dripping with water, (Al-albani 4324, Bukhari 3441 and 3440) some scholars said this means he has visible pure sweat, others said this is a metaphor for his beauty and freshness, so it's AS IF his head is dripping with water, the prophet ﷺ also said: "...His head drips with water, and if he lowers his head, the water drops from him in the form of several successive drops, and if he raises his head to the top, the water slowly descends from him, and its drops are large like pearl beads..."

•the one who resembled him most was Urwah ibn Masʽud (RA)

•he'll be wearing two Thobes dyed with a yellow hue (Al-albani 4324)